# $wpdb - Unable to count no or registered users in plugin table-Wordpress

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins

I am using a plugin event Registration for wordpress. Everything just works fine. 
But I need to display the no of attendee or registered users in the page or widget.

I am using this code to display the no, but did not work..

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->evr_attendee" );
echo "<p>User count is {$user_count}</p>";

?>
```

This code works great if I replace `evr_attendee` with `users`. I observed , the code just works great for wordpress database tables and does not work for external plugins, Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$wpdb` is an instance of the wpdb class, which is defined in `wp-includes/wp-db.php`. Those "table names" are actually variables defined inside the class.

This will work:

```
if (!isset($wpdb->tablename)) {
$wpdb->tablename = $table_prefix . 'tablename';
}
```

Or simply you can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table_prefix_evr_attendee
```

Comment: Thanks Moeed, It Actually Worked Great. Could you please explain what exactly it does to fix it?

Comment: `$wpdb` is restricted to its internal predefined tables it wont work with custom table.thats why I have provided two ways 
1) Edit your pluggin
2) use simple table prefix which is by default (wp_)